# How to tell Application Insights to ignore 404 responses

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

ApplicationInsights has recently started mailing me a Weekly Telemetry Report.  My problem is that it tells me that I have a bunch of Failed Requests, Failed Dependencies, and Exceptions, but when I click through to analyze the failures I see that they are all associated with attempts by bots or Bad Guys to access nonexistent pages in my website.

Is there an easy way to tell ApplicationInsights that I am not interested in metrics associated with attempts to access nonexistent pages?  Yes, I appreciate the Weekly Telemetry Report, but I don't want to have to take the time to investigate a category of frequently reported problems that I consider "false positives".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can filter AI telemetry by implementing a [Telemetry Processor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling/#filtering).
For example, you can filter out 404 Not Found telemetry by implementing the ITelemetryProcessor 'Process' method as follows:

```
public void Process(ITelemetry item)
{
    RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = item as RequestTelemetry;

    if (requestTelemetry != null && int.Parse(requestTelemetry.ResponseCode) == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Next.Process(item);
}
```

Comment: You should check if requestTelemetry.ResponseCode is null. I don't know when it happens, but I just had the case

Comment: That happens when the request has been cancelled or timed-out I believe.

Answer (score 37):

You can modify the request telemetry and mark it as a `Success` (not `Fail`). This way, the request will be properly logged by the AI but as a successful one.
You need to implement a [Telemetry Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

Example:

```
public class CustomTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        switch (telemetry)
        {
            case RequestTelemetry request when request.ResponseCode == "404":
                request.Success = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the better answer, because the requests are properly logged, but don't show as failure.

Comment: The only thing that I am missing here is the fact that my dependency (db returning 404) is gone

Comment: @MarkLagendijk is correct. Requests should be logged, but not as errors